# integrate GitHub with AWS code build so that my test cases are triggered and executed in AWS build

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, amazon-ec2, github-actions, aws-codebuild

**Background**: My project and test cases are within the gihub repo. I created test.yaml file in GitHub that triggers a workflow in GitHub Actions whenever devs create a push or pull request on main branch. Lot of test cases pass except for end to end scenarios that has dependency to connect to Database hosted in AWS. I was told to create a code build project in AWS and integrate it with GitHub so that the build gets created in AWS and tests are run there.
**Question:** Problem is all my secrets and variables are listed in GitHub secrets. what should be the buildspec.yaml file look like? I do not want to create secrets again in AWS secret manager. is there a way to export them or bypass this step? Can you provide me guidance on how my buildspec.yaml file should look like in AWS?

this is my current test.yaml workflow file in GitHub.The project is in gradle.

```
name: Karate Test Workflow

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Java
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: '17'

      - name: Cache Gradle packages
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          path: ~/.gradle/caches
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-gradle-${{ hashFiles('**/*.gradle') }}
          restore-keys: ${{ runner.os }}-gradle

      - name: Grant execute permission for gradlew
        run: chmod +x karatetest/gradlew

      - name: Build and run Karate tests
        working-directory: ./karatetest
        env:
          KARATE_OPTIONS: ${{ vars.KARATE_OPTIONS }}
          KARATE_ENV: ${{ vars.ENV }}
          TEST_API_URL: ${{ secrets.APIURL }}
          CONNECT_TIMEOUT: ${{ vars.CONNECT_TIMEOUT }}
          READ_TIMEOUT: ${{ vars.KARATE_READTIMEOUT }}
          RETRY_COUNT: ${{ vars.KARATE_RETRYCOUNT }}
          RETRY_INTERVAL: ${{vars.RETRYINTERVAL }}
          TEST_USERNAME: ${{ secrets.DATAINGEST_DB_USERNAME }}
          TEST_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.DATAINGEST_DB_PASSWORD }}
          TEST_URL: ${{ secrets.DATAINGEST_SERVER_URL }}
          TEST_DRIVER_CLASS_NAME: ${{ secrets.DRIVERCLASSNAME }}
          TEST_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: ${{ secrets.KAFKA_SERVER }}
          TEST_GROUP_ID: ${{ vars.GROUPID }}
          TEST_API_USERNAME: ${{ secrets.API_USERNAME }}
          TEST_API_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.API_PASSWORD }}
          TEST_NBS_URL: ${{ vars.NBS_URL }}
          TEST_WRONGAPIURL: ${{ secrets.WRONGAPIURL }}
        run: |
          ./gradlew test \
            -Dkarate.options="$KARATE_OPTIONS" \
            -Dkarate.env="$KARATE_ENV" \
            -Dtest.apiurl="$TEST_API_URL" \
            -DconnectTimeout="$CONNECT_TIMEOUT" \
            -DreadTimeout="$READ_TIMEOUT" \
            -DretryCount="$RETRY_COUNT" \
            -DretryInterval="$RETRY_INTERVAL" \
            -Dtest.username="$TEST_USERNAME" \
            -Dtest.password="$TEST_PASSWORD" \
            -Dtest.url="$TEST_URL" \
            -Dtest.driverClassName="$TEST_DRIVER_CLASS_NAME" \
            -Dtest.bootstrapServers="$TEST_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS" \
            -Dtest.groupId="$TEST_GROUP_ID" \
            -Dtest.apiusername="$TEST_API_USERNAME" \
            -Dtest.apipassword="$TEST_API_PASSWORD" \
            -Dtest.nbsurl="$TEST_NBS_URL" \
            -Dtest.wrongapiurl="$TEST_WRONGAPIURL"

      - name: Upload Karate Test Report
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        if: always()
        with:
          name: karate-report
          retention-days: 1
          path: |
           ./karatetest/build/cucumber-html-reports/
           ./karatetest/build/karate-reports
```

Answer (score 0):

One way could be to pass the secrets through environment variables. However, **I don't recommend it** as the secrets would be visible in the AWS logs and under the environment variables.
That said, you could use the GitHub action [AWS CodeBuild run build](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/aws-codebuild-run-build-action-for-github-actions):

```
- name: Run in CodeBuild
  uses: aws-actions/aws-codebuild-run-build@v1
  with:
    project-name: your-project-name
    buildspec-override: path/to/buildspec.yml
    hide-cloudwatch-logs: true # Disable stream to hide secrets.
    env-vars-for-codebuild: first_secret,second_secret
    env:
      first_secret: ${{ secrets.first_secret }}
      second_secret: ${{ secrets.second_secret }}
```

Then in your `buildspec.yml`, you can type `$first_secret` and `$second_secret`. Or, if you're using the [GitHub Action runner](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/action-runner.html) with `${{env.first_secret}}`, `${{env.second_secret}}`.

---

A better approach involves pushing your secrets to AWS before running CodeBuild. In your workflow, you can run the following:

```
aws secretsmanager create-secret --name your_secret_name --secret-string ${{secrets.MY_SECRET}}
```

Remember to configure the [AWS creds](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/configure-aws-credentials-for-github-actions).